# Me aparece un "IndentationError: expected an indented block" cuando tengo el código indentado

Tags: python, sintaxis

Tengo el siguiente código con distintas funciones, pero me sale un error de indentación, cuando ya está indentado.

¿Alguien me ayuda a ver el fallo?

No entiendo el motivo por el cual me falla, he buscado información y todo lo que encuentro es de gente que NO a indentado, sin embargo, yo sí que lo he hecho.

También me comentaron que debería poner espacios en vez de tabulador pero si lo pruebo con espacios me sale el mismo fallo.

```
import hashlib
import os

def Llegir_Usuari():
    try:
       archivo = open("usuaris.txt")

       print(archivo.read())

       archivo.close()

    except FileNotFoundError:

          print("Error 80")

          exit()

    vacio = os.stat("usuaris.txt").st_size
    if vacio == 0:

       print("Error 82")

def Inicia_Sessio():

    usuari = input("Escriu el nom del usuari: ")

    contrasenya = input("Escriu la contrasenya: ")

    contrasenya = hashlib.sha512( str(contrasenya).encode("utf-8") ).hexdigest()

    d = {}
    with open("usuaris.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
            (key, val) = line.split()
            d[key] = val
    if usuari in d:
        valor = d[usuari] 
        if contrasenya == valor:
            print("Error 74")
        else:
            print("Error 72")
    else:
        print("Error 70")

def Força_bruta():

    usuari = input("Usuari a petar: ")

    d = {}
    with open("usuaris.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        (key, val) = line.split()
        d[key] = val

    if usuari in d:
        valor = d[usuari]
        arxiuPass = open("passwd.txt", "r")
        for x in arxiuPass.readlines():
        
            F = x.strip("\n")

            F = hashlib.sha512(str(F).encode("utf-8") ).hexdigest()

            if F == valor:
                print("Contrasenya: %s - Has resolt: %s" %(str(x.rstrip()),str(F)))
            
    arxiuPass.close()

menu = True


while menu == True:
    print("¿Qué vols fer?\n")
    print("2) Llegir un usuari \n")
    print("3) Iniciar sessió amb un usuari \n")
    print("4) força bruta \n")
    print("5) Sortir\n")
    
    funcio = input("Escriu el número de la funció que vulguis fer: ")

    if funcio == "2":
        Llegir_Usuari()
    if funcio == "3":
        Inicia_Sessio()
    if funcio == "4":
        Força_bruta()
    if funcio == "5":
        menu = False
    else:
        print("Opció no valida")
```

Este es el fallo:

```
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Por mucho que busque en Google no consigo encontrar nada que me sea de utilidad, ya que cómo os he comentado, todo lo que encuentro es de gente que directamente no indenta.

Me han comentado que podría ser culpa del sistema operativo en el cual ejecuto el programa, pero lo ejecute en windows o en debian 10 me aparece el mismo error.

¿Que debería hacer?

Por favor, necesito ayuda y no sé donde más buscar.

Comment: Tal como está el código de tu pregunta si falta indentar. No está indentado el contenido del with en la función Força_bruta.

Comment: Ya lo he identado con un tabulador, pero me sigue apareciendo el mismo erro

Comment: Como te han dicho antes, tal vez los tabs no sean buena idea. Prueba agregando 4 espacios.

Comment: SI, ya lo he hecho y nada. Sigue apareciendo el mismo error

Comment: Conviene que pongas el error completo. Tienes problemas de identación en la línea 33.

Answer (score 1):

Python utiliza la indentación como delimitador de bloques de código (lo que otros lenguajes marcarían poniendo begin/end o bien abriendo y cerrando llaves).

Por tanto toda sentencia que lleve a continuación un **bloque**, debe llevar indentado ese bloque. El fin del bloque lo marcará el regreso a una indentación anterior. Esto aplica a `with`, `for`, `while`, `def`, `class`, `if`, `else`, etc. En realidad es sencillo reconocer qué sentencias esperan un bloque después, porque todas esas sentencias finalizan la línea con dos puntos.

En tu código hay dos sentencias `with`, una en la línea 32:

```py
    with open("usuaris.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
            (key, val) = line.split()
            d[key] = val
```

y otra en la línea 50:

```py
    with open("usuaris.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        (key, val) = line.split()
        d[key] = val
```

como ves, en ambos casos la línea siguiente al `with` está a la misma altura que el `with` y no más adentro. Esto causa el error que python te señala. Python esperaba una indentación mayor, porque esperaba el inicio de un bloque (ya que la línea anterior terminó con `:`)

La solución no es tan simple como añadir espacios por delante de la línea siguiente. Hay que pensar un poco mejor cuál es la estructura del código y qué instrucciones quieres que formen parte del bloque iniciado con `with` y dónde se termina el bloque `with`.

Por ejemplo, en la línea 32 sí que bastaría añadir espacios por delante del `for` para dejarlo así:

```py
    with open("usuaris.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            (key, val) = line.split()
            d[key] = val
```

y eso haría que el cuerpo del  `with` contuviera simplemente la línea con el `for` (la cual a su vez termina en dos puntos por lo que inicia otro bloque interno, en este caso con dos instrucciones).

Pero si en la línea 50 te limitas a añadir espacios delante del for y dejarlo así:

```
    with open("usuaris.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
        (key, val) = line.split()
        d[key] = val
```

obtendrías un nuevo error, pues en este caso es el bloque interno del for el que no está indentado (está a la misma altura que el `for`). La solución en este caso no es añadir cuatro espacios delante del for, sino cuatro espacios delante de cada una de las líneas del bloque, es decir, dejarlo como en el caso de la línea 32 antes visto.

Por otro lado, si seguimos mirando lo que va a continuación de la línea 32, una vez arreglado el error, vemos que el conjunto se ve así:

```
    with open("usuaris.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            (key, val) = line.split()
            d[key] = val
    if usuari in d:
        valor = d[usuari] 
        if contrasenya == valor:
            print("Error 74")
        else:
            print("Error 72")
    else:
        print("Error 70")
```

Aquí vemos que el `if` que aparece después tiene la misma indentación que la línea con el `with`. Eso indica que ese `if` ya no pertenece al bloque with, y que el bloque with por tanto solo contiene el `for`.

Eso para Python es perfectamente correcto, pero sólo tú como programador sabes si es realmente lo que quieres hacer o no. ¿El `if` debe ejecutarse como parte del bloque `with` o no? Si es que no, entonces la sintaxis era correcta, pero si es que sí, entonces deberías haber indentado todo ese código (el `if` con todo lo que contiene) para dejarlo así:

```py
    with open("usuaris.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            (key, val) = line.split()
            d[key] = val
        if usuari in d:
            valor = d[usuari] 
            if contrasenya == valor:
                print("Error 74")
            else:
                print("Error 72")
        else:
            print("Error 70")
```

En este caso particular ambas soluciones serían válidas, ya que lo único que hace el bloque `with` es que todas sus instrucciones se ejecuten mientras el fichero abierto con `open()` esté abierto. Al terminar el bloque `with` el fichero se cierra (y la variable `f` deja de ser accesible). Por tanto en este caso lo mismo da cerrar el fichero antes de los `if` que cerrarlo después y ambas sintaxis darían un funcionamiento correcto.

### Moraleja

La indentación en python es parte de la sintaxis, no es sólo un detalle estético. Y no sólo afecta a que puedas obtener errores de sintaxis, sino a la estructura misma del código y por tanto de lo que va a ejecutarse. Revisa siempre con cuidado que la indentación refleja la estructura lógica de lo que pretendes hacer.

Otro consejo importante: usa siempre espacios para indentar el código, no lo mezcles con tabuladores porque aunque visualmente parezcan lo mismo, no lo son y ciertas mezclas confunden a Python. Por ejemplo si en un bloque una línea está indentada con tab pero la siguiente con cuatro espacios, aunque en el editor se vean igual, python lo rechazará (porque el hecho de que un tabulador se muestre con cuatro espacios es cosa de tu editor, otro podría mostrarlo de otra forma y por tanto el uso de tabuladores es ambiguo). Lo dicho, usa siempre espacios, o configura el editor para que cada vez que pulses la tecla TAB, meta cuatro espacios en lugar de meter un tabulador.